# MYSQL LIKE but not equal

Tags: php, mysql

I have got database with this structure

```
Id      Country         Interests
12      Azerbaijan      Acting,Reading
14      Azerbaijan      Reading,Writing
16      Azerbaijan      Acting,sleeping
```

And this PHP/MYSQL

```
$Interests = "Acting,Reading";

$Country = "Azerbaijan";
$query = "SELECT * FROM user_opt WHERE Country='$country' AND Interests='$Interests' ";
$i = substr_count($Interests,',');
for($j = 0; $j <= $i; $j++) {
   $a = explode(',', $Interests);
   $query2 = "SELECT * FROM user_opt WHERE Country='$country' AND Interests LIKE '%{$a[$j]}%'";
}
```

So with this code it returns me this ids

```
12
12
16
12
14
```

But i want it to return 
12
16
14

Comment: use "distinct"  in mysql

Comment: How exactly can i use it in my code? @MaheshMadushanka

Comment: Distinct in  not useful becuase  you are not select rows in one select but you are repeating  multiple select ...

Comment: Seriously consider normalising your data.

Comment: Consider using paramaterized queries

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use OR to find all of your interests. To do that, build up your OR statement first, then insert it into the query. NOTE: This is not a secure/preferred way of doing this! Make sure you're using PDO or mysqli and bind your parameters!

```
$interestArr = [];
foreach($Interests as $Interest) {
    $interestArr[] = "Interests LIKE '%{$Interest}%'";
}

$query2 = "SELECT * FROM user_opt WHERE Country='$country' AND (".implode(' OR ',$interestArr).")";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can avoid the loop using  a regexp

```
SELECT distinct *  
FROM user_opt 
WHERE Country='$country' AND Interests REGEXP 'Acting|Reading';
```

Comment: It is still the same result

Comment: without  loop  ...Impossible .. show  me the code  you really used

Answer (score 0):

I did it using

```
!=
```

Like this

```
$query2=$con->query("SELECT * FROM user_opt WHERE Country='$country' AND Interests!='$Interests' AND Interests LIKE '%{$a[$j]}%'") or die($con->error);
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to loop the result, just using OR comparator

```
$Interests = "Acting,Reading";

$Country = "Azerbaijan";
$query = "SELECT * FROM user_opt WHERE Country='$country' AND ("     
$a = explode(",", $Interests);
$interestQuery = "";
for($j = 0; $j < count($a); $j++) {
    if($j+1 == count($a))
        $interestQuery = $interestQuery . "Interests LIKE '%". $a[$j] ."%') "
    else
        $interestQuery = $interestQuery . "Interests LIKE '%". $a[$j] ."%' OR" 
}
$query = $query.$interestQuery;
$echo $query;
```